# Is there a word for when racism is used in a power dynamic?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am wondering if there is a specific word that can reference a type of racism used through abusing a socioeconomic power dynamic wherein one group controls vastly more resources than another. I thought I heard of such before, but I cannot remember it. Example sentence:

> Due to the ______ that oppresses this racial group, the resulting socioeconomic disparity has caused higher unemployment, higher incarceration rates and increased victimization.

Comment: Welcome to English Stack Exchange. If you have any questions, please consult the Help Center. As it stands, your post seem to lack a detailed explanation on what abusing a socioeconomic power dynamic truly means in this context, as well as an example in which the word could be used. I'd highly suggest that you make an edit to address these issues.

Comment: I'm looking for a general case, this is as specific as I can make it.

Comment: Are you thinking of "Jim Crow"?

Comment: [Institutional racism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Institutional_racism) is a very general term that became common in the 1960s.

Comment: There is also [Supremicism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supremacism), which can be race based.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean by *type* of racism? And what do you mean by *abusing a socioeconomic power dynamic wherein one group controls vastly more resources than another*?

Comment: It should be straight forward in the English language. Suppose one group has control over a lot of socioeconomic resources like white people in North America, not that I am suggesting anything negative about anyone, and then suppose that power is used to disparage other groups through legislature, propaganda, policing, hiring, etc, many aspects of society.

Comment: One common definition of racism itself is "racial [prejudice plus power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prejudice_plus_power)"—could that be what you were remembering?

Comment: I don't necessarily agree with that specific interpretation because racism through abuse of power is just one way that racism can be carried out, and I am looking for what can describe that generalization to any way.

Comment: Could you please construct a sentence, using a blank in place of the word you are seeking?

Comment: This is the English language site right? Is this the wrong place for words and grammar? "Due to the ______ that oppresses this racial group, the resulting socioeconomic disparity has caused higher unemployment, higher incarceration rates and increased victimization."

Comment: @GaneGoe - It seems to me that "prejudice" is the best fit for your sample sentence.

Comment: Well prejudice isn't strictly pertaining to race so it doesn't solve the issue, but I think you have the right idea.

Comment: This almost sounds like it could fill in your blank, or replace your sentence entirely: “The wealthy elite have adopted racism as a divide-and-distract mechanism. It is 100% a divide-and-distract weapon of the 1% against the 99%.” https://soundcloud.com/user-830442635/trumps-dog-whistles-are-now-a-howl-ian-haney-lopez

Comment: I don't know what soundcloud has to do with this but the issue is coming up with a word to describe a circumstance such as what you've presented but that is focused on race, but not strictly that issue because wealth is just one want in which a power dynamic can be sustained, there is also military force, legislature, etc.

Comment: GaneGoe, if it’s really "straight-forward" what are you asking and why?

ELU isn’t interested in writing styles or proof-reading, but since you’re here, what would bewaring with “Due to the racism that oppresses this group”?

Comment: The purpose is a consensus on efficient communication of the concept. Race-based issues are obviously something that have come up often throughout the history of every government, so I would expect a word that can accurately describe such circumstance. I could waste time saying something unnecessarily complicated like "in a position of fringe influence within the constraints of society..." or, I could just say "marginalized".

Answer (score 1):

**[Disenfranchisement](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disenfranchisement)** in a broad sense may be what you seek. It focuses on the loss of privileges, immunities or rights via a socioeconomic imbalance of power, causing the gap to increase. While it is especially focused on one's right to vote, it covers all the major points of institutionalized racism that you mention.

Comment: That's a good word I hadn't thought of, thanks. I am wondering however if this differs from marginalization simply by the focus being on voting.

Comment: It has since had an extension of meaning for any form of disempowerment. Marginalization is also good.

Answer (score -2):

Form the leftist point of view, what you are seeking is Capitalism.

“The embodiment of capitalism is racism, thus resulting in socioeconomic disparity, higher unemployment, incarceration rates and victimization.”

GaneGoa, I understand the textbook definition and my answer isn’t about judging the morality or political aspect of Capitalism. Capitalism is the word you are looking for.

What audience would receive the idea that there is racism and social justice is required? This is what Capitalism means to these audiences if they were to read your start sentence.

Audience: Antifa, BLM, Democrats >> High unemployment, economic disparity and racism are the symptoms and Capitalism is the disease.

Audience: Typical Trump Voter >> Capitalism is not a zero-sum gain but rather a mechanism of unlimited opportunity of wealth for everyone in America. This negates racism and etc.

Audience: Typical Economic Statist >> Capitalism is a zero-sum gain and wealth is not created.

Your opening sentence would likely alienate the majority in a random sample. Therefore write for the audience who recieve your ideas.

Comment: I've never heard a single economist suggest that at any of the universities I'm in contact with, nor anyone of any political affiliation. I haven't seen that capitalism is confined to any kind of race relation, it is only that in the instance of a zero sum game that some individuals will be more prosperous than others. That particular system can be chosen to disparage a particular race for said gains, but that is not a guaranteed circumstance as it is already irrational to prevent individuals from either attaining higher capital or contributing or the economy based on race.

Comment: GaneGoe, it depends upon who your target audience for whom will read what you are authoring. My answer could right on target, it may not be on target.

Comment: A general audience, a random sample from the U.S. public.